# How to store accelerometer values

Tags: android, progress-bar, accelerometer

I have this code:

```
public class Chronom extends Activity 
{

    Chronometer mChronometer;
    ProgressBar progre;

    int total=1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main7watingscreen);

        //Start Chronometer
        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono1);
        mChronometer.start();

        progre = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        MyCount counter = new MyCount(31000,300);
        counter.start();
    }


    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer
        {
            public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
            {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Chronom.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                total++;
                progre.setProgress(total);         
            }   

        }
```

and i want to store accelerometer values (x, y and z) inside a vector for example (can be other form i want to know your opinion).

But i want to do this at the same time as the progress bar is fulling ( it stops after 30 sec). Like begin the storing at 1 sec and stop after 30 sec.

If you don't understand my question please say it and i will explain it better.

How to do it?? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain sensor values every time they're changed, through the `onSensorChanged()` callback (see the [SensorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html) reference). **You can't query the sensor data at a set time**.

**There is a way around that**: have a listener saving the values every time they change (i.e., inside the `onSensorChanged()` method), and query those saved values using your timer. For example, you can use a `static float[]` array for it or `SharedPreferences` values.